# How to program a toolbar on top of windows phone keyboard?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to add a "hide button" each time the keyboard shows up so that user can see all the screen when he needs to.

In iPhone this toolbar exists, is it possible to do the same for windows phone anyhow ?

Comment: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-hide-the-soft-keyboard-in-a-windows-phone-app

Comment: @hob that's usefull to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot change** the default keyboard. Still [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx) is a tutorial to create a custom keyboard on Windows Phone 7.